# GnuPG and CreateProcess in Delphi Service

Tags: delphi, service, pgp, gnupg

Trying to use [GnuPG](http://gnupg.org/) with Delphi (Win32). I need to sign some file with such console command:

> `"C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG\gpg.exe" -a -u Alex --passphrase secretpassword --yes --clearsign -o C:\Result.asc C:\InputFile.txt`

First I created normal VCL Forms App and used `CreateProcess` function, everything was OK, but when I transfered that code to my service app, gpg.exe exits with code 2. Maybe I missed something? Any ideas?

**Update**

Just in case someone has such a problem. GnuPG stores keys in `C:\Documents And Settings\<username>\Application Data\gnupg\` but when service runs from another user account (SYSTEM) - it can't find your key. GL & HF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dumping stderr and see if you get anything. You may be able to pipe the message in. It could be a problem reading the passphrase. I sort of remember having to pipe the passphrase into gpg instead of specifying it as a parameter.

Comment: Yep, that was pretty much it. I got 'clearsign failed: secret key not available' from stdErr...

Comment: Then you've got to specify `--home` as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a (child of a) service app, there is no shell as parent, so the child apps might simply be unable to use stdio.  Attempt to execute with cmd /c   or via shellexecute. Or better, use a program that doesn't always require stdio.